# Is it illegal to write code that could potentially disable developer tools in a browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-security

I know you cannot disable the tools without changing the registry but is it illegal to block the user from hitting F12 or inhibiting them from accessing developer tools at all?

I ask this because there is a discussion going on about web accessibility and I'm trying to find proof that you should not do this.  Please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: Stupid?  Yes.  Annoying as hell?  Most definitely.  Will it stop me ever trusting anything that you coded?  Absolutely!!  Illegal though?  No.

Comment: You can easily access developer tools from the browser menu in most browsers anyway.
If you're trying to secure your content, then web dev isn't for you.

Comment: I don't think it's a big deal to leave it up.  I just want to make sure I have all the facts before saying that it is something we shouldn't do or worry about.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the main reason for wanting to disable developer tools? I'm not clear on that yet.

Comment: All valid points.  Keep them coming of ways around this.  As I said, I am in agreement with your response, minus Archer calling me stupid.  I just want to find enough logic and evidence to say this is not a good idea to worry about.

Comment: Block F12, sure....but what about context menus and the option in the toolbar. It is not going to happen.

Comment: The answers need to live on the server, that is the solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, I think I have everything I need to make a logical case.

Comment: There is no way to prevent someone who even knows about developer tools in the first place from using it via web page javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is IE, and the user is in a corporate environment where she is on a crippled desktop and does not have the right/permission to install other programs like Firefox, Chrome then my answer is "No, it's not illegal."
The computer belongs to the employer and he decides who does what, assuming the user is expected to fulfill a very specific well-defined job.